# jQuery handler not defined (handler.guid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, handler

i have a function for attaching handlers to events and it's working when a pass it an anonymous function but when i declare the function as a field in the object it doesn't work and the handler is undefined

```
validationObj  = (function(API){

    this.validate = function (id2, idN2){
         //code


        //doesn't work 
        //this way i get an handler.guid error  on  functionFromMyApi 
        API.attach_events( {"keyup": run_func(id1, id2) },"id");


        // work's ok
        API.attach_events( {"keyup": function(){ 
                                       // same code here from run_func
                                     }
                            },"id");

          //code
    };


    var run_func = function (id1, id2){

         var obj1 = document.getElementById(id1);
         var obj2= document.getElementById(id2);

         var show_err = false;


         API.functionFromMyApi ();



         //code 
         // more code

     };


})(api);
```

**i use jQuery 1.2.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
API.attach_events( {"keyup": run_func(id1, id2) },"id");
```

you're not passing it a function reference, like you do when you use an anonymous function, you're instead calling `run_func` and passing its return value. If `run_func` had no parameters then you could do:

```
API.attach_events( {"keyup": run_func},"id");
```

However, since it does, you're still going to need to use an anonymous function:

```
API.attach_events( {"keyup": function() {run_func(id1, id2)} },"id");
```

Comment: what is weird is that i enter with debugger in the run_func, it's running ok and when i return to API.attach_events( {"keyup": run_func(id1, id2) },"id");  i get the error. 
I would expected to get the error at entering the run_func.

Comment: i run it without parameters just to see the result and it works ok